# Alamofire 4.4 with Swift 3.1 'Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nshttpurlresponse

I'm updating app from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.1. I've got several errors ;/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU1Dh.png)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please don't post your code as picture and instead post your code here as text. It help us to actually debug it properly.

Answer (score 0):

With the version of swift from 2.3 you must have to update the Alamofire along with it.
The current version of Alamofire is 4.4

Do update your pod file and check the [Readme](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) file , Everything you need is already mentioned there. Do let us know if you are facing issues with it.

Comment: and yes do post your code from next time instead of image please, will help us to test your case in playground...Keep Coding